# Skype for Windows 8 (Metro) not staying logged in using Microsoft credentials

Tags: windows-8, login, skype

I installed Skype through the App Store yesterday (I'll refer to it as Metro Skype).

During installation, it prompted me to merge my old Skype username with my Windows 8 account, which happens to end in `@hotmail.com`. This is a photo of the screen I took yesterday (I apologise for the quality. I didn't think an actual screen capture was necessary at the time):

[image: Merge accounts]

Now, when I open Metro Skype, I am not prompted for a login at all. It goes through the animation, **logs me in**, and then a few seconds later, **kicks me out** with the following error:

[image: Oops, there was a problem.]

At last count, after rebooting, uninstalling, removing Skype references from everywhere I could find them, I was up to five "Try again" attempts.

---

Here's the interesting part:

- The account merge was successful. I can log into the latest Skype for OS X, using the Microsoft credentials, or the old credentials. Either one of them works, and it keeps me logged in.
- I can log into the `Skype for desktop` application on Windows 8 as well, but *only* with the old credentials. If I use the Microsoft ones, it kicks me out after a few seconds.
- The Skype.com website allows me to log in with either of my two credentials.

---

My question is, how do I get into the Metro Skype settings to tell it not to use my Windows 8 credentials, if at all possible? I've swiped and clicked and swooshed and sworn and nothing seems to change the display. I've been into my personal settings to tell Skype not to run in the background, but that seems to be it. I can't see a reference to Skype in my User settings under Windows 8 either.

If this is not possible, I will remove it, and simply continue using the `Skype for desktop` application as before. But I want to play with the new hotness.

Comment: You sure this just isn't an issue on Microsoft's end?

Comment: Mine was a live account, and it merged ok. May be it's a problem with hotmail.

Comment: @Ramhound - It's probably a problem on Microsoft's side, but I want to be sure.

Comment: @KumarBibek - it's unlikely it's a problem with Hotmail, since I can log in with the MS credentials on the website and on the OS X Skype.

Comment: Same issue here, constantly getting kicked out so I decided to stick with the usual Skype for Desktop.

Comment: Figured it out. See my answer below. Messenger was signed in from elsewhere, which forced a disconnect using MS credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been a very long-time user of MSN Messenger, under all of its iterations.

Today as I installed Skype 6.1, I tried one more time to sign in with my Microsoft credentials. As I was doing that, I remembered that my Messenger account only allows me to sign in from one place at a time.

So I signed out of Messenger in Adium, and Skype stayed logged in with my Microsoft credentials.

Winner winner, chicken dinner.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Uninstall Metro/Modern Skype.
2. Uninstall desktop Skype if you have installed it.
3. Open up `regedit`, find and delete all keys that contain the word `Skype`:
   [image: Skype]
4. Navigate to `%LocalAppData%\Packages` and delete any folder that contains the word Skype.
5. Install desktop Skype.
6. Login in desktop Skype as usual.
7. Reinstall the Metro/Modern Skype.
8. Login in Metro/Modern Skype and check if the issue persists.

EDIT: Another suggestion:

1. Create a new local account.
2. Logout from the Microsoft account.
3. Install Metro/Modern Skype.
4. Login in and check if the issue persists.

Comment: Thanks. Did that and no change. That was during the part I described as "At last count, after rebooting, uninstalling, removing Skype references from everywhere I could find them, I was up to five 'Try again' attempts." I will vote you up though for a good suggestion.

Comment: Installed as local account, the old credentials work, the new ones do not.

Comment: Wait for sometime or contact MS support. It's an issue on their side.

Comment: Yup, I guess I'll have to. Even with my certifications and partnership agreements, talking to tech support is less than exciting.